# Why TCPDF is deleting the Header Logo?

Tags: tcpdf

I am working on TCPDF and every time I generate my PDF it deletes the logo in the folder.

How can I prevent it?

Here's my code:

```
            public function Header()
        {
            // Logo
            $image_fileHeader = K_PATH_IMAGES . 'logo.png';
            $this->Image($image_fileHeader, 'C', 6, '25', '', 'PNG', false, 'C', false, 300, 'C', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Github's tracker, recent releases have problems with image caching that leads to `unlink`ing used images ([#159](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/issues/159), [#158](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/issues/158), [#153](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/issues/153)). Hit that wall myself recently.

As of Jan 2020, there is no official fix available at the moment. There are pull requests awaiting, but since TCPDF is [officialy obsolete](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF#important), the "right" path would be to downgrade to version `<6.3`. There are compatibility warnings with PHP 7.4, but at least it does not remove images :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Here's a bit of code that copies the missing image.
Comment out the echo lines since tcpdf has to be the first thing to output headers.

```
<?php 
// Routine to replace logo img if deleted by tcpdf
// This happened twice while testing

$logo_filename = '/home/patriot/public_html/assets/logos/patriot.jpg';
if (file_exists($logo_filename)) {
    // echo "<BR>The file $logo_filename exists";
} else {
    // echo "<BR>The file $logo_filename does not exist";
    $backup_logo = '/home/patriot/public_html/assets/patriot.jpg';
    if (!copy($backup_logo, $logo_filename)) {
    // echo "<BR>failed to copy $file";
    } else {
    // echo "<BR>Success COPYING $backup_logo TO logo_filename";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did comment the unlink of image in the `tcpdf.php` line 7799 to 7803

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).